# How to create a dataframe from urlopen (csv)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My code:

```
# parse json returned from the API to Pandas DF
openUrl = urlopen(url)
r = openUrl.read()
openUrl.close()
#d = json.loads(r.decode())
#df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(r, index=[0])
```

The error:

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Help would be aprreacited.

Answer (score 1):

The DataFrame constructor requires an nd-array like input (or dict, iterable).
You can use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) if you want to directly input a csv and get a DataFrame.
Try printing `r` to see what is actually inside the response.

`pandas.read_csv` has a lot of option parameters to handle different types of csv, which of course depends on what you're getting from the url.

Comment: OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type

Comment: If the content at the url is a csv, you should be able to `pandas.read_csv(openUrl)` (It can handle an object with a `.read()` method) However, it seems that `urllib.Request.read()` return a bytestring, not sure if that works.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet might help you.

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
r = urllib.request.urlopen('HERE GOES YOUR LINK')
x = r.read()
print(type(x))
y = str(x)
df = pd.DataFrame([y], columns=['string_values'])
print (df)
```